# how to provide authorisation to grails services using xfire plug in to grails spring security based application?

Tags: grails, spring-security, xfire

I have grails app using spring security plugin,i need to expose some of its services as web services so using xfire plugin,How can i give security to these services?,

With advance thanks,
Swati

Answer (score 0):

I do not know, whether the xfire plugin itself has capabilities to be wired with the spring security plugin. However you can explain the spring security plugin to always require authentication or to require authentication for specific URLS, just like /xfire-interface/**. See

1. http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html#5.2%20Simple%20Map%20in%20Config.groovy 
   and
2. http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/5%20Configuring%20Request%20Mappings%20to%20Secure%20URLs.html

Comment: there is a Ws-security for grails app using xfire wired with acegi-plugin,i want to know if same i can use with spring-securirty based

Comment: there is a Ws-security for grails app using xfire wired with acegi-plugin,i want to know if same i can use with spring-securirty based